# "First Post" review audit thought the answer was link-only, when a URL was the answer

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

Today I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17026970), which earned me a 4 day review ban. I got a review ban a while back, also for incorrectly reviewing a link only answer, which made me extra careful with links inside answers.

However in this case I don't think this is a link only answer, as this does provide an answer to the question (why does this API URL not work). Although I agree this is not a post with the highest of qualities, I think a link only flag would not be in place here, and therefore makes this post a poor candidate for review audits.

Comment: Looking through your history, it strikes me that you do not choose to "Edit" *nearly* often enough when looking at "First Posts" and "Triage". You're right that they are on-topic and do not need to be flagged, but many of them *do* need to be edited, either to format code, add line breaks, or just to remove chatter like "Thanks in advance". I mean, jeez, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17003432) you *commented*, but didn't suggest an edit? Come on! Anyway, that's the only real problem I see in your recent reviews. Other things look good, so ban lifted. Please edit more!!

Comment: Thank you. Also thanks for the tips. Although I don't have full editing priviliges yet.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but you can still suggest edits. And when a post needs to have code formatted *and* chatter removed, then that's a substantial enough edit that you should be suggesting it. If you never actually edit anything, then you aren't really improving the site with reviews. You're just kicking the problem down the road.

Comment: What you need to do first of all in this case, is to consider if you have a clue what the answer (and question) is all about. It is apparently about something called [tag:yahoo-oauth]. Personally I know absolutely zero about this, I don't understand a thing written in the answer. I can't tell if it is relevant nor if it is some manner of link-only answer. This would be where I would click the 'skip' button, which is always a perfectly fine thing to do.

Comment: I just want to point out (as someone who doesn't have full edit privileges either) that sometimes the reason I only comment when reviewing a post instead of suggesting an edit is because another edit has already been suggested/pending, and hence I am not allowed to make any suggested edits. I can see that it wasn't the case here and that the OP could have edited the post, but I just wanted to say it's not always the case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reviewers didn't pay attention to the question, and to the answer. This is what happens when people almost-blindly hit the delete button when they see a URL.

Actually, the URL *is* the answer, and not a link to some resource. In this case and it shouldn't be deleted, I voted to undelete.

Comment: That's what I thought as well.

Comment: So can we give these 4 people a review ban ;) https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16822052

Comment: Probably not, but we can set an audit for the audit.

Comment: Oh wow, that is a bit of a tricky one, and it really does show how many of the reviewers in the "Low Quality Post" queue just blindly trigger on answers with links. Everyone in the other review queues ("Late Answers" and "First Posts", which this was in multiple times) got it right. Everyone in "Low Quality Posts" got it wrong.