# Why was my flag declined on this link-only answer?

Tags: support, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290774/7496073) as Not An Answer, but it was declined with "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" even though it consists pretty much entirely of a documentation link.

Was the review incorrect, or is my understanding of what makes an answer link-only completely wrong?

---

The answer has since been deleted by its original author. Its complete text is shown below:

> Take a look at the [Media Player Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer)

Comment: So, there's user with access to moderator tools privilege that can take a screenshot of the corresponding Q&A pair? Cody only provided link to some of deleted answers which may be about the question, or not?

Comment: @Braiam I quoted the entirety of the answer in this question. If you want a screenshot of the full Q&A, it's [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEVkf.png).

Comment: For me it was an answer but with very low quality.

Answer (score 8):

It is a link-only answer, according to the [accepted definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer).

The answer you flagged amounts to saying "you can find an answer if you look at the Media Player Framework". That pretty much falls under the "apples are sold over there" example from the famous apples post.

Comment: Shog referred to this difference in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288055/please-define-link-only-answer#comment165606_288056): `Difference between "there might be beer down the street" and "the house beer at tomersh's pub is good".` Media Player Framework is a specific name of a framework that can be used for the answer. Something like "There's a framework to do this already" without naming it is like your "apples are sold over there," but not like this answer, which gives a specific answer.

Comment: Pointing to something that can be used for the answer does not constitute an answer, unless the question is "what can I use for accomplishing this and that". Providing pointers to resources or documentation describing how to do stuff is not sufficient, the answer must remain valid and applicable even if the resource is no longer available.

Comment: Could you provide a source for that claim? The [accepted definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/7795130) says for the example "The answer can be found over here: <link>" that "Notice that this is not necessarily the same thing as 'link-only answer' (although there is much overlap). In particular, answers where the link itself is the answer to the question are excluded and should not be flagged. For example, where the link text is a function/API and the link target is the associated documentation."

Comment: If/When the resource becomes unavailable, it says to flag "only if you cannot improve the post yourself and the only possible solution is deletion. Examples of ways to fix a low-quality link-only answer are:    Editing in the pertinent information from the link. Try to summarize the information in your own words and quote relevant parts..." So this is not to be flagged as not an answer if it can be edited.

Comment: My personal opinion is that these effortless answers should be burned with fire, but that is not the accepted definition of link-only as you claim. I think it's silly that the bar for deleting these is so low that only the most worthless junk can get deleted by the flag, and that we're supposed to save posts when we can instead of straight up deleting them. But that's not what the accepted definition of Link-Only says, and it's not how moderators have repeatedly said these should be handled. If you want to change to how such answers are considered or handled, you'll need a feature request.

Comment: There's a difference between a link to a function/API and a link to framework. It's obvious how to use a function or API entry - you call it. How do you use a framework? There's a million of different ways, but basically you read the documentation, find out how to add it to your project, find out how to initialize it, find out which API or functions to call. Saying "use this framework" does not actually provide any information at all. No information => not an answer.

Comment: The Media Player Framework *is* the answer. It's the difference between someone handing you a beer in a bottle, and someone pouring it into your mouth. What you're saying is, the delivery wasn't good enough. They didn't open the bottle and pour it into your mouth. Or, they didn't walk the person through exactly how to use the framework. Those are downvote reasons, not deletion reasons. You are also, like John, missing the real issue, which is the question.

Comment: The question is too broad and is basically asking for a tutorial, but sometimes questions like this may turn out to be OK, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python). Returning to the beer analogy, I view this question to be more akin of "how can I make a beer", not "where can I find a good beer".

Answer (score 4):

### Not an answer vs Very low quality flags

There's [so much confusion about these two flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-an-answer?sort=votes&pageSize=50), I treat them [identically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one) <sub>note</sub>.
For a flag on a post like this, I wouldn't decline the flag. The answer is basically a link to a framework. Yes, the framework is an answer, but it is low quality as it stands and should be a comment as a hint to the OP. If an answer is flagged as 'not an answer' and is 'very low quality', I mark the flag as helpful and vice versa. Working on the premise that the flagger is acting in good faith and trying to communicate that it's a lousy answer.

### Declining flags

I don't subscribe to following the '[letter of the law](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-letter-of-the-law)' when handling flags, but rather the '[spirit of the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law)'. Everyone volunteers their time on here and if people are attempting to curate the site, it's better to support them in how to do this, without being too officious about it. It's a problem on the site and in society generally, that I suspect is a part of human nature.

When a person flags many answers to one question as 'not an answer', often in the case when the question asks for an offsite resource. I will tend to decline those flags to push the flagger towards flagging the question for closure instead. Often they are answering the question, but the whole question and answers need to be deleted. My view is, it's about getting rubbish off the site as easily as possible. Raising multiple flags to achieve something that could be done with one flag is time wasting.

I decline flags for one reason:

***To teach people how to flag effectively.***

If the flag serves the same purpose, by bumping the post into the review queues or the mod queue for possibly deletion and should ultimately be deleted, I mark the flag as helpful. If the post shouldn't be deleted, I decline it.

### Handling the flag by deleting the question

When handling answer flags I usually check the question, as it's not uncommon for poor answers to be posted under poor questions. It's important to treat the source.

Instead I would close and delete the question, as the question is too broad.  Deleting the question would delete the answer and automatically mark the flag on the answer as helpful.

When deleting a question I generally leave a comment:

> Please raise a mod flag to have your question undeleted if you edit it to be on topic. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

<sub>note

With the one exception that a low quality flag that is marked as helpful, automatically applies a downvote to the post.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It isn't link-only under [the accepted definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer):

> …answers where the link *itself* is the answer to the question are excluded and should not be flagged. For example, where the link text is a function/API and the link target is the associated documentation. Another example can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355035/first-post-review-audit-thought-the-answer-was-link-only-when-a-url-was-the-a/355037#355037).
>
> [A handy rule-of-thumb is to strip the markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer): if it's still an (attempted) answer without the link, then it's an answer and should not be flagged.
>
> [image]

The link text there is the name of the framework that should be used; the link is merely supplemental. If you strip the markup, it's still an answer—albeit a bad one.

When you come across answers like this, it pays to look at the question. That's what I did. Also, you kind of have to, because you can't adequately judge whether or not something is an answer unless you at least skim the question to which it is attached.

In this case, the question was asking something very broad, but this answer does, in fact, provide a direct answer to it. According to this answer, if you want to add Apple Music Connectivity to your iOS app, then you need to use the Media Player Framework. It also included a handy, optional link to the documentation for that framework.

Of course, when looking at the question, you'll also notice that it sucks. A large part of the suckage is owed to the fact that it solicits answers like this one. That's why I closed it at the same time as I declined your flag on the answer.

Comment: Almost any link to a framework is going to have the framework's name in it though. By that logic they're all valid answers.

Comment: Question: *"How do I compile C code?"* Answer: *"Use [the gcc compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/)"*. Is it an answer? Well, yeah. Is it a bad answer? Well, yeah. Could someone possibly write a better one? Umm, dunno. Do you flag it? No. Do you flag the question? Yes.

Comment: I mean, that just seems like a ridiculously low bar to clear if the only thing they have to do is mention the name of the thing they're recommending. Edit: is something wrong with tagging in comments right now? The auto-complete didn't pop up and then when I typed it manually it disappeared after posting.

Comment: There's no point in pinging the person whose post you're commenting on, because they're going to get notified anyway. Yes, our bar for what constitutes an answer is pretty low. Moderators don't judge the technical correctness or usefulness of answers. That's done with votes. You still seem to be missing the fact that whether or not something is an answer depends on the question it purports to answer. This one did answer the question. I don't see any way in which it failed to do that. Do you, @John? Can you explain to me where this answer failed to be relevant to the question being asked?

Comment: The question didn't ask for a framework, they asked "what I would need to do" and "how to add it into my app." Sure, the information they need is *somewhere* in the link, but again that logic can apply to most link-only answers.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The information is in the text of the link (What I would need to do? [Use] the Media Player Framework). Now, that might be a wrong answer, but it is an answer to the question. Being wrong or otherwise not useful is a reason to downvote, but not necessarily to flag. The answer is an answer, regardless of the link. If it had said "Take a look at [this](example.com)", then it would be link only, but it contains "Media Player Framework" which is enough to get over that very low bar of being "only a link." Wrong answers aren't to be flagged.

Comment: @DavyM So you're saying we should never delete *any* links to frameworks/libraries then?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I'm saying an answer is not link only when it contains any content outside of the link. If removing the link to the framework leaves nothing in the answer, then it is link **only**, emphasis in the word **only**, but if removing the link leaves words that answer the question, it is no longer **only** a link. We're talking about the link only close reason here, and the word only is the key to what gets deleted for that reason and what doesn't.

Comment: @DavyM So what would have made that answer link-only, then? The name of the framework is in the URL, after all.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The name of the framework is in the text of the URL. Link breaks, the name still stands. If the name weren't there, then yes, it would be link only.

Comment: @DavyM So that answers my question then. Don't ever bother flagging totally-not-link-only answers because the bar is so low it's literally impossible for them to not make it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yup, that bar has been discussed many many times already, and that is the community consensus: [Link + Direction = No Longer a Link-Only Answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380862/7795130), [Please define “link only answer”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288055/7795130), [Link Only Answer - Not An Answer Declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311753/7795130)... each of these are like you describe, and the consensus has been that the bar is so low you can barely trip over it.

Comment: [Example of "not an answer" because link-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290622/how-to-fetch-list-of-contacts-and-send-messages-with-react-native/55292902#55292902). [Here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194752/366904). Don't like those? Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292596/wordpress-how-to-show-header-on-every-page/55292710#55292710).

Comment: I can't see any of those...

Comment: @John Ah yes, that's because I deleted them. While you wait to earn 10k, [here's an amalgamated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eHEa.png).

Comment: Are any of those links to frameworks/libraries? Does the URL include the name of it?

Comment: I have no idea what the URLs are. It doesn't matter. I don't click on URLs when processing flags.

Comment: So if they had text that said the same thing the last part of the URL does like the one I flagged, they'd be fine?

Comment: Only if that text was also an answer to the question that was asked. So...no.

Comment: Except it's NOT an answer to the question, because they didn't ask for just the name of it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The community consensus is somehow that "off-topic" answer can't be deleted via flag. At least those "name-only" answer are "better". After all, the question is deleted already...

Comment: @JohnMontgomery then it is a low quality answer, but it is still an answer, so the Not An Answer flag doesn't apply. I know it is hard to wrap one's had around the nuances between the two and the exact usage of the Not An Answer flag (as it is a bit different from what you'd expect just from the name - a bad answer is still an answer), it took me a couple of rejected NAA flags to learn it as well. However, if you see an attempt at an answer that results in a bad answer, downvote it and leave a comment on it rather than flag it as NAA.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Just repeatedly saying that the answer is wrong, or bad, or otherwise not a *good* answer doesn't change the fact that it's still an answer.  NAA if for things that *Aren't even answer*, not for answers that you don't like.  If you don't think that's a good answer then *vote on it*, rather than casting a flag that's just demonstrably not true.  After all the flag doesn't say, "not a good answer".

Comment: @user202729 For what it's worth, I have no problems deleting off-topic answers in response to flags. But you have to be careful, because NAA flags come without context. I'm probably going to notice when it's a PHP answer to a C++ question being flagged, and delete without prejudice, but if it's anything less obvious, you are better off raising a custom flag where you can explain why the answer needs to be deleted. The point is merely that moderators don't judge technical correctness or usefulness, so its lack of relevance needs to be stark, obvious, and unarguable.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say I think it's wrong or bad, I said it isn't an answer - the only question it could conceivably answer is "What is the name of a framework that does this?" My point is that I don't see how just mentioning the name of the thing that contains what they need is meaningfully different from a link to it (and apparently at least 18 other people agree with my interpretation).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery No, you're saying you don't think it has *successfully* answered the question.  NAA is for things that are not *attempts* to answer the question.  That you think it *fails* to answer the question, due to a lack of detail, is something you're free to reflect in your vote.  That lots of other people like to falsely claim that just because an answer *fails* to answer the question it should be flagged as NAA doesn't make it any less incorrect.

Comment: @Servy A link also *attempts* to answer the question. How is a name any different? That's my point.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery So you think no one should ever be allowed to provide an answer describing an existing product that solves the problem described?  How does that *not* answer the question (at least when done well, which this particular answer does not)?  A link isn't providing an answer, it's indicating an answer might exist elsewhere.  Stating a particular product that solves the problem *is* providing a solution.  There are certainly suggestions on how to do that *well*, but the basic idea of suggesting a project is certainly considered appropriate here, and is an answer.

Comment: @Servy I think that if you're going to provide an existing product that solves the problem, you need to actually explain how it does that and not just drop its name. Otherwise you're not solving the problem, you're telling them where to go to solve the problem, which is *exactly the same thing as posting a link.*

Comment: @JohnMontgomery That would be the difference between a high quality, and low quality, answer, yes.  That doesn't make it not an answer at all though.  Others have already described how naming a product and linking a website are different, I don't see the need to repeat them.

Comment: @Servy If I tell you the name of a framework, you have to Google it and read through the documentation to figure out how to apply it to your situation on your own. If I give you the link to a framework, you have to follow it and read through the documentation to figure out how to apply it to your situation on your own. Nobody has explained the distinction between those two scenarios in any meaningful way.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery You're going to go need to look up the product even *if* someone provides additional information (if you intend to actually use it).  There's no way around that.  That you think the answer is incomplete, again is entirely justifiable cause for asserting it's a low quality answer, but that doesn't mean it's not an answer.

Comment: @Servy I can't help but notice a complete lack of explaining the difference between the two in your reply.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Like I said before, others have explained the differences between the two, I don't see a reason to repeat them.

Comment: @Servy Such as? I haven't seen any such comments as I already said.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381637/why-was-my-flag-declined-on-this-link-only-answer/381638?noredirect=1#comment680567_381663

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381637/why-was-my-flag-declined-on-this-link-only-answer/381638?noredirect=1#comment680595_381663

Comment: There is no difference between an answer telling you the name of a framework, and an answer giving you a link to a framework. They're exactly the same answer. This was an attempt to answer the question because it provided the name of a framework. That it had a link was altogether irrelevant. See "strip the markup" in the quoted text. I have no idea why you're trying to draw that distinction. "Link-only" is also irrelevant. The criteria is always, "Does this answer impart any useful information?" Did you read the quoted text in my answer? It is *specifically* about this case.

Comment: @CodyGray So that goes back to my original question: since there's no meaningful distinction between a framework's name and a link to it, is there *any context* where a link to a framework would be considered link-only?

Comment: "Link only" is a really bad criterion for assessing answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh? Because I've heard "link-only" thrown around as a valid use of the Not An Answer flag plenty of times in the past, so if it's literally impossible for a framework link to not be an answer then you should probably communicate that better.

Comment: I'm really confused here. What part of [the linked, official guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) is unclear? We've tried to address *all* of these concerns.

Comment: @CodyGray The part where it attempts to answer the question, because the only question it could conceivably answer is an off-topic one.

Comment: @John which is close to saying "it's an answer". Albeit short and possibly an answer to an off-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

As always, problematic questions leads to problematic answers. Remember, answers do not exist in a vacuum. They *are* related to the question. Saying "You need to indent your code" can be a improvement on formatting or an answer depending on whenever or not you formatted your code or you are asking how to format your code.

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEVkf.png) is very lousy. Says that "there's an API" but doesn't specify which API it's talking about. What problem has he with the API it has found? There's too much lack of information, that answerers can (and did) suggest anything and it may be considered an answer.

The guidance specifically says that there's only one exception for using the not an answer flag, and it is when the question is asking for non answers. In this case, the question was so low quality that it attracted equally low quality content. The bar of what qualify as an answer is usually set by the question.