# "Low Quality Posts" review audit failed on basically a link-only answer

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

I just failed [this low quality posts review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24058827), which granted me a temporarily review ban. The answer only contains a hint to look into the Microsoft docs which is from my understanding a link-only-answer, which should be deleted.

> **Links to an answer**
>
> [...]
>
> If there's nothing in the answer itself to even hint at which direction we're being pointed in, it's not an answer and should be deleted.
>
> In other words:
>
> ```
> The answer can be found over here: <link>
> ```
>
> -> [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: That's not link only, it says the name of the tool OP should look at to solve their problem

Comment: To be honest, I tend to agree it's not a very good answer. It even makes a point out of stating that the poster might not have understood the question and then pointing to a tool that will "maybe help". However it needs to be really terrible to have any flags actually stick to it.

Comment: @MaximilianAst If you're ever not sure you can click the link to go to the post in context, which will often help, especially in the case of audits

Comment: The answer's author was inactive for a year and a half, and in a couple of days they get 10 upvotes in three answers about MS Teams. They found their niche.

Comment: Remember, if in doubt, just skip or, you could ask on here for clarification.

Comment: [Apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381637/why-was-my-flag-declined-on-this-link-only-answer) site policy is that something isn't link-only if it mentions the name of what it's referring to. Which I still think is stupid, but it is what it is.